# Book ID: YA involving space and time travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, young-adult

I read this book probably 12-13 years ago, in my high school library. Here's the specifics I remember.

1. I'm reasonably sure the title had the word "Crystal".
2. The story follows a girl. At the beginning of the story she visits a library, when she leaves it she meets a stranger. She thinks the stranger is going to shoot her but instead they pull out a handkerchief.
3. She meets a boy and falls in love. She is crew on a spaceship leaving earth. He ships out to surprise her but dies in cryosleep, along with one other passenger.
4. I'm unclear on the next bit, but the girl ends up alone on the ship. She journeys to the edge of the universe and watches it collapse, and a new Big Bang. She travels through time to her own era, and becomes the stranger her past self meets in front of the library.
5. She becomes a scientist and clones herself. She becomes the second passenger who dies on the way to the ship.
6. Her clones end up saving the world, I really don't recall much about the end of the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [*The Starlight Crystal*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/137967.The_Starlight_Crystal) by Christopher Pike.

> It is two hundred years in the future and 18 year old Paige Christian has been given a chance to join the crew of the Traveler, a special spaceship designed to circle the solar system at near light speed. One day aboard the Traveler is equal to ten years on Earth. It is a time capsule as well as a spaceship whose purpose is to study the changes on earth throughout two centuries, and then return home. Something awful happens to the ship and the Earth and the years pass, billions of them, and still Paige Christian lives, and remembers all those she left behind. Until the day she finally does come home to a world and a future no human being could have imagined!

[image: Cover image]

Comment: Wow that was fast! That is the book, thank you!